# pymodbus AsyncModbusTcpClient hace demasiados intentos de conexion

Tags: python, plc

tengo una api con fastapi que conecta con plc's por modbus/tcp. Si la conexión falla quiero que no haga más reintentos. En la documentación pone que como parámetro retries=0, pero sigue haciendo tres intentos de conexión.

También probé max_reties=0 que vi en otro sitio e incluso crear una excepción, pero hasta que no hace los tres intentos fallidos no lanza la excepción. Aquí la función:

```
@router.get("/plc_registers")
async def plc_registers(plc: Plc):
    value_register = []
    bool_decoder = None
    ret = 0

    while not bool_decoder and ret < 5:
        try:
            client = AsyncModbusTcpClient(plc.host, plc.port, retries=0)
            await client.connect()

            sleep(ret)

            boolean_reg = await client.read_holding_registers(
                plc.bool_register, plc.bool_register_count, unit=plc.slave_plc
            )

            if plc.int_register:
                int_reg = await client.read_holding_registers(
                    plc.int_register,
                    plc.int_register_count,
                    unit=plc.slave_plc,
                    retries=0,
                )

            bool_decoder = Decoder.fromRegisters(
                boolean_reg.registers, wordorder=Endian.BIG, byteorder=Endian.BIG
            )

            for i in range(1, len(boolean_reg.registers) * 2 + 1):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    bits = bool_decoder.decode_bits(i)
                    value_register.extend(bits)
                    bool_decoder.reset()
                    bits = bool_decoder.decode_bits(i - 1)
                    value_register.extend(bits)
                    bool_decoder.reset()

            if int_reg:
                value_register.extend(int_reg.registers)

        except AttributeError as e:
            ret += 2
        except Exception as e:
            ret += 2

        finally:
            client.close()

        if len(value_register) == 0:
            for i in plc.variables_list:
                value_register.append(False)

    return dict(zip(plc.variables_list, value_register))
```

Answer (score 0):

He hecho un cambio y ahora llamando a AsyncModbusTcpClient con un with solo hace un intento.

```
try:
    async with AsyncModbusTcpClient(plc.host, plc.port) as client:
        try:
            boolean_reg = await client.read_holding_registers(
                plc.bool_register,
                plc.bool_register_count,
                unit=plc.slave_plc,
            )

            if plc.int_register:
                int_reg = await client.read_holding_registers(
                    plc.int_register, plc.int_register_count, unit=plc.slave_plc
                )

            bool_decoder = Decoder.fromRegisters(
                boolean_reg.registers,
                wordorder=Endian.BIG,
                byteorder=Endian.BIG,
            )

            for i in range(1, len(boolean_reg.registers) * 2 + 1):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    bits = bool_decoder.decode_bits(i)
                    value_register.extend(bits)
                    bool_decoder.reset()
                    bits = bool_decoder.decode_bits(i - 1)
                    value_register.extend(bits)
                    bool_decoder.reset()

            if int_reg:
                value_register.extend(int_reg.registers)

        except Exception as e:
            if len(value_register) == 0:
                for i in plc.variables_list:
                    value_register.append(False)
        finally:
            client.close()
except Exception:
    if len(value_register) == 0:
        for i in plc.variables_list:
            value_register.append(False)

return dict(zip(plc.variables_list, value_register))
```